# how to give more space in acronyms between the abbreviation and the expansion

Tags: spacing, acronyms

I like to give more space in acronym between the abbreviation and the expansion

CR Collarette Ratio
DCAC Discrete Circular Active Contour

using acronym package

Comment: How are you creating your acronyms? With `acronym`? With `acro`?  With `glossaries`?

Comment: using acronym package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refedine or patch `\@acf`. The following example replaces the space with dots:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@acf{\nolinebreak[3] }{\nolinebreak[3]\ldots}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ac{foo}

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{foo}{long description of foo}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Replace `\ldots` in the above code with whatever space you want.

If you also want to change the appearance in PDF bookmarks you also need to redefine/patch `\acfa`.